# Function with exponent imaginary power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If we have $u=\frac{4c(e^{-is}-e^{is})}{(e^{-is}+e^{is})^2} \tag 1$

where c is a constant and s is a variable.   Can we write $e^{is}$ in terms of u ? Means Can we write $e^{is}$ as $\psi(u)$ , a function of u only, from the given definition?

Comment: Let $Q=e^{is}$. Then $e^{-is}=Q^{-1}$, so you can rewrite the right side in terms of $Q$. When you do that, can you solve for $Q$ as a function of $u$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Sir, bit confused abt ur question.Please check the answers  typed by Panda and me below.. I think that will solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you:

[image]

If you have other problem ask it.

Comment: So $e^{is}=\sqrt{1-sin^2(s)}+i sin(s)$. This we can write as interms of u as u had shown ..Am I right

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

What about using $$e^{is}=\cos(s)+i\sin(s)$$  $$e^{-is}=\cos(s)-i\sin(s)$$ I am sure that you can take from here.